# Error 403 clicking link in Google Code

Tags: google-code

When I click the "dialone" link on [this Google Code updates page](http://code.google.com/u/115096232762407076040/updates), it gives a 403 error.

I would guess the dialone project has been deleted, but in that case wouldn't the link be disabled by Google's smart engineers?

Or is the project really deleted and it is a bug in Google Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume you do not have proper permissions to view this link. There could be various reasons why.

For Example the content that was previously on that link may no longer exist.

This most likely is a bug.